# Python IDLE not opening due to Tcl/tk error

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, python-idle

I have just installed the latest version of Python 3.6.5 from python.org. I am using 64 bit Windows 8.1 .Earlier it was showing all kinds of .DLL errors, I tried installing all the updates and C++ Redistributable but nothing happened, then I manually downloaded all different DLL's and pasted them in the System-32 folder. By doing that the python command shell did start working but as soon as I try to open the IDLE, nothing happens, no error message is shown and nothing pops up on the monitor. 
I read a lot of answers on the net and when I tried writing "import tkinter" in the python command shell it shows that the module not found and this message also - " import _tkinter # If this fails your python may not be configured for Tk" .
Please resolve this issue.

Comment: Why would C++ have anything to do with python? It sounds like you need to download the latest python release and reinstall. The tkinter library comes with the windows distro for python. You should provide the actually trackback error you are receiving.

Comment: If you tried to start IDLE from a Command Prompt command line, you would see the import error.  Since IDLE uses tkinter, which uses _tkinter (the C coded bridge to tcl/tk), it fails immediately.

Answer (score 0):

If you did not have the C runtime (CRT...) .dll MS Visual C++ applications compiled with VS2015 or VS2017, including Python since 3.5, it is very likely because you turned off automatic Windows updates.  If you got interactive Python working, you must have gotten the right one installed.

If _tkinter is not installed, it must be because the box for optionally installing tcl/tk, _tkinter, tkinter, and IDLE was not checked when you said 'install'.  If you still have the installation file where it was when you ran it, you can go to the Control Panel installed programs dialog, click on 3.6.5, and ask to 'Repair'.  You should be able to add the needed checkmark.  Otherwise rerun or redownload the file from python.org.

If you need further help with installation questions, the python.org python-list is sometimes a better forum.